# In statistical terminology, what is the opposite of "peak"?

Tags: terminology, curves

When we see a curve (or a normal distribution), we describe the highest value as "peak".

Let's imagine we have a curve with only a minimum value (like an inverted hat), what do we call that minimum value?

Comment: I've also heard trough.

Comment: what do you mean by curve? I guess curve is more mathematical that statistical.  if you mean a mathematical concept it is called minima. I am interested in knowing a continues density function with just a minima.

Comment: Basically it just like a function and then you have one minima.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [signal processing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008SBBJQW), a commonly used term is [negative peak](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642664403). In mathematics, you use the terms [vertex of parabola](http://hotmath.com/hotmath_help/topics/vertex-of-a-parabola.html), highest or lowest point, maximum or minimum.

Comment: This doesn't look like an accurate description of how mathematics understands parabolas.  Indeed, it is rare indeed for any neighborhood of any local extremum of a density function to be part of a parabola, so the term "vertex of parabola" would almost never apply in this context.

Answer (score 8):

“Trough” is commonly used, although perhaps somewhat colloquial.

Comment: I say "trough" all the time, but I've never thought of it as particularly informal.

Answer (score 5):

The peaks are called "local modes" (specifically, the x-value is called the mode, the height would be the density at the mode).

The highest one is sometimes called "*the* mode".

The bottoms of troughs are often called "antimodes"

Comment: It's worth noting that this term actually appears in statistical literature. It sounds a lot clunkier than "trough" though. Statisticians aren't always known to come up with clever terminology.